# Migrating rxdart from 0.18 to 0.24

Tags: redux, rxdart

I've upgraded to the most recent version of flutter and I've started going through now and upgrading the packages I use as well. I've noticed there are some breaking changes that have happened in several packages, but the breaking changes in the rxdart package have got me stumped.

the developers have kept up their changelogs and mentioned in 0.23.0 they removed the observable class as seen [here](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart/changelog) and they even made a codemod package to try to make the migration easy, which can be seen [here](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart_codemod). this repaired only a couple of my issues, and left several more.

```
Epic<AppState> getConversationPreviewsEpic(ConversationRepository repo) {
return (Stream<dynamic> actions, EpicStore<AppState> store) {
return Stream(actions)
    .whereType<SubscribeConversationPreviews>() // <-- subscribe to conversations stream
    .where((action) => action.fromUser != null)
    .switchMap((action) {
      isConversationLoading = true;
  return repo
      .getConversationPreviewStream(action.fromUser, lastSnapshotAction: (lastTimeStamp, hasMore){
        lastConversationTimeStamp = lastTimeStamp;
        hasMoreConversations = hasMore;
      })
      .map((rooms) => ConversationPreviewsSnapshot(rooms)) //<-- when new conversations come in add them to the redux store
      .takeUntil(actions.where((a) => a is UnsubscribeConversationPreviews)); //<-- unsubscribe from conversations stream
});
};
}
```

all of the issues I have are similar to this one here. I wish I could underline stuff in red like my editor does here. So on line 2 of the code block where it says

```
Stream<dynamic> actions
```

I get an error that Stream isn't a type
and then on the next line

```
return Stream(actions)
```

I get an error that Stream() doesn't take any arguments. I take away the arguments and the redline goes away but I can't test to see if the code still works because I can't figure out how to fix the first error.

One last thing, fromIterable and fromFuture don't work anymore and I don't see in the documentation how to adjust them to make them work again

Comment: I have had similar issues and not able to fix it. `BehaviorSubject<Map> _value;
  Stream<Map> get value => Rx.merge([
        _value.stream,
        _onValueChangedStream,
      ]);`

Answer (score 0):

RxDart 0.24.x based on extension method, call methods on `Stream` directly.

```dart
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

actions.whereType< SubscribeConversationPreviews >();
```